# Good Concrete Material for Small Scale Sculpture Casting?

Tags: material-selection, concrete, material-sourcing

I am interested in incorporating concrete casting as a material into a series of sculptures. Here are my parameters:

1. The concrete will mainly be used as a framing element for wall works, so rectangular shapes with a couple smooth curves between different points of elevation. Dimensions will be something like 3' L x 2' H by 2-3" D at an absolute maximum, and can be smaller / thinner depending on the piece.
2. I want to achieve a smooth polished concrete finish on these elements, high brutalist is the aesthetic! So something I am able to
   wet sand or otherwise polish until it is smooth and shiny.
3. I will need to embed threaded inserts and other pieces of hardware into the concrete to attach other sculptural elements
4. Something as non-toxic as possible, preferably that I can work with with my bare hands without getting a chemical burn, and also without
   silica dust if possible. I am able to take basic safety precautions
   like a respirator and rubber gloves, but would like to avoid toxic
   elements as much as possible for a material process I plan to reuse.

How can I go about sourcing a sculpting concrete that meets these requirements? Very new to all this! Are there any brands that have worked well for y'all or any specific parameters I should be looking for?

Also very much appreciate any process advice to achieve these results in  relation to the concrete I source.

Comment: A friend of mine at the academy made large concrete sculptures, consisting of relatively slender bars. I believe he used a regular (fine) concrete mortar for this, bought from a hardware store. Have you tried that yet?